# POST using Bash in Script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am currently writing a script which gets a cookie and unique URL from a website, then uses that cookie and URL to post login/password information.

I am having trouble in getting this to work, some of the runs I have done gives me the message "switching from POST to GET" and I can't understand why.

Can someone please help me?

```bash
for i in $(cat accounts.txt); do
    rm out.out
    curl -L -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt  https://website.com | grep -Eo "(http|https)://cookies.website.com/idp[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*" >> out.out
    url=`head -1 out.out`
    content="$(curl -X POST -L -v -b cookies.txt -d "$i" "$url" )"
                    echo "$url" "$i" "$content"
                    done
```

Comment: Probably because the server is returning a redirect, and `-L` means to follow redirects. Redirects always use `GET`.

Comment: It still uses `POST` to post the data to the original URL, then uses `GET` to get the output.